# Python create matrix and select rows depending on list values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 values 1,2,3 and a 2 length permutation of 4 strings A,B,C,D to which I included a 2 length combination of each of the 4 strings with itself for a total 16 elements in the list.

I want to create a matrix from the 3 values such that each of the 16 elements is associated with a row in the matrix. The strings and shown headers are not part of the matrix. Just select the rows if the associated string is encountered? How do I create the matrix?

Example:

```
        A       B       C       D
"AA"    1       2       2       2
"BB"    2       1       2       2 
"CC"    2       2       1       2 
"DD"    2       2       2       1 
"AD"    3       2       2       3 
"AB"    3       3       2       2 
"CB"    2       3       3       2
"BC"    2       3       3       2
```

etc. This is the pattern 16 times. i.e if string is same value e.g AA, col A will be 1 and the rest will be 2. 
if string is different e.g DB or BD, cols D and B will be 3 and the rest will be 2

I could only generate the list but the matrix I have is as good as doing it manually so no need to even show. Here is how I generated the list even though I think it is not even remotely efficient.

```
import itertools

a = list(itertools.permutations('ABCD0', 2)) #added 0 in order to get 2 repetitions of 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
b =[]
for i in a:
    if i[0] == "0":
        change = i[1]
        c = (change,) + i[1:]
        b.append(c)
d = a + b
e = [(i) for i in d if "0" not in i]
f = [list(elem) for elem in e]
g=[]
for i in f:
       g.append( (''.join([w+' ' for w in i])).strip())
h = [elem for elem in g if elem.strip()]
j = [e.replace(" ","") for e in h]
print(j)
```

J is a list

```
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BA', 'BC', 'BD', 'CA', 'CB', 'CD', 'DA', 'DB', 'DC', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Build a data frame which maps whether your indexes contain your columns or not.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=list('ABCD'), index=j)
```

You can do that using `str.contains`

```
map_df = pd.DataFrame([df.index.str.contains(x) for x in df.columns],
                      columns=j, 
                      index=list('ABCD')).T
```

This will create a data frame where cells are `True` if there is a match between columns and rows (for example, row `"AB"` and columns `"A"` and `"B"`) an `False` otherwise

```
    A       B       C       D
AB  True    True    False   False
AC  True    False   True    False
AD  True    False   False   True
BA  True    True    False   False
BC  False   True    True    False
BD  False   True    False   True
CA  True    False   True    False
CB  False   True    True    False
CD  False   False   True    True
DA  True    False   False   True
DB  False   True    False   True
DC  False   False   True    True
AA  True    False   False   False
BB  False   True    False   False
CC  False   False   True    False
DD  False   False   False   True
```

Now, you can check which rows consist of the same char duplicated (e.g. `"AA"` or `"BB`) using `regular expressions`

```
>>> r = df.index.str.match(r"(\w)\1{1,}")
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

And using operator `~` and `.iloc`, you can use `applymap` to define your logic to specific sets of rows

```
map_df.iloc[~r, :] = map_df.iloc[~r,:].applymap(lambda k: 3 if k else 2)
map_df.iloc[r, :]  = map_df.iloc[r,:].applymap(lambda k: 1 if k else 2)

    A   B   C   D
AB  3   3   2   2
AC  3   2   3   2
AD  3   2   2   3
BA  3   3   2   2
BC  2   3   3   2
BD  2   3   2   3
CA  3   2   3   2
CB  2   3   3   2
CD  2   2   3   3
DA  3   2   2   3
DB  2   3   2   3
DC  2   2   3   3
AA  1   2   2   2
BB  2   1   2   2
CC  2   2   1   2
DD  2   2   2   1
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems I will have to learn more about pandas which I will do. Do you mind just a minimal explanation of some critical lines to your answer? That will help me understand when I read the doc. Please give me an example of how you will compare a string to print its corresponding values in this method. I see values for DD is incomplete but from the other results I assume it is correctly 1.

Comment: @Starter I tried to explain every step of the way. Please get back to me if anything is confusing :)

Comment: Awesome. Now I understand what is going on. I will go study pandas doc and look at regex. Understanding is critical for me.

Comment: so given the result, how will I select the row of values for a list like ['AA', 'AB', 'BC', 'CB']. I am bit confused looking at the doc right now with iloc and the rest. I assume the result provided is merged right